# Can't forward ports to LXC

Tags: networking, iptables, lxc, network-bridge

Trying to access container's apache from host. Container IP is 10.211.55.24 and if I try `curl 10.211.55.24:80` it works.

This is the default lxc profile:

```
config:
  environment.http_proxy ""
  user.network_mode ""
description: Default LXD profile
devices:
  eth0:
    nictype: bridged
    parent: br0
    type: nic
  root:
    path: /
    pool: default
    type: disk
name: default
used_by:
- /1.0/containers/web
```

I have launched the container (when asked to create a bridge lxbr0, I chose No, right? Profile already has br0). Then I configured a br0 in my host machine with:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto enp0s5
iface enp0s5 inet manual

auto br0
iface br0 inet dhcp
    bridge_ports enp0s5
    bridge_stp off
    bridge_fd 0
    bridge_maxwait 0
```

Enabled ipv4 forwarding and added this iptables rule:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -i enp0s5 --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.211.55.24:80
```

But then `curl 127.0.0.1:80` fails.

Comment: Just noticed that I can't also access the network from within the container. This is Ubuntu running in Parallels (bridged) and then LXC bridged in Ubuntu. The Ubuntu host is now on the 192.168 subnet and LXC also creates a 192.168 IP. No network...